# Make points visible at same coordinates: Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot multiple points in the same coordinate, but with a small offset distance, so it's possible to see all the points.

I have an N-by-M matrix example:

```
[0, 12, 7,  10, 0, 12;
 0, 7,  7,  10, 0, 7 ;
 7, 12, -3, 0,  7, 7 ;
 0, 10, 4,  0,  7, 10];
```

I want on the x-axis to be `1:M` in this case `x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

The y-axis should be the colums, so at `x=1` it should plot `[0,0,7,0]`
but this only gives me two different visible points (at `[1,0]` and `[1,7]`). The other points are hidden underneath the last point plotted at `[1,0]`.

How is it possible to plot each of the points with a dot, and add a small offset (between -0.1 and 0.1) to the `x` and `y` coordinates of each dot, to
make the different dots visible?

Comment: It was a mistake, I just removed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shifting by some small amount to increase visibility is (probably) a bad idea...

- Introduces inaccuracies to your plot
- May not actually make things much clearer

A better option would be to use concentric circles, by varying the point size using `scatter`.

```
% Set up matrix for plotting
m = [0, 12, 7,  10, 0, 12;
     0, 7,  7,  10, 0, 7 ;
     7, 12, -3, 0,  7, 7 ;
     0, 10, 4,  0,  7, 10];
x = 1:size(m,2);
% Unique elements in the matrix (could use tolerancing here)
u = unique(m);
% Set up sizes of each point
s = zeros(size(m));
for ii = 1:numel(u); 
    c = cumsum(m == u(ii),1);  % Running total of matching value in columns
    s = s + c.*(m == u(ii));   % Increase point size by number of points
end
s = (s*5).^2; % Scatter takes square-points size, times 5 for scale
% Plot each row
figure; hold on;
for jj = 1:size(m,1)
    scatter(x, m(jj,:), s(jj,:), 'linewidth', 1.25); % Using the sizes we just made
end
hold off; grid on; xlim([0,7]);
```

Output:

[image: plot]

This method has the advantage of immediately seeing "hotspots" in your data where there are many points. Also, whilst the colours *are* more visible, colours aren't necessary for reading the plot. This is convenient when working with greyscale print-outs or colleagues with colour-blindness.

---

A similar but alternative method would be to give each row its own size, then the size/colour is consistent. You just don't get the "hotspots" and you may get a large circle with no smaller ones inside it - making it harder to see the actual data point location.

Comment: I really like your plot, but when I've tried to insert your code in my function, but it doesn't plot all the points, do you know why?

Comment: m=[7,7,4,4,7,12,7,10,7,2,12,12;2,0,2,2,2,7,4,7,4,0,4,12;7,7,-3,7,10,7,4,10,2,7,-3,10;7,12,12,7,2,12,4,12,10,7,10,-3];

x = 1:size(m,2);
u = unique(m);

s = zeros(size(m));

for ii = 1:numel(u); 
    c = cumsum(m == u(ii),1);columns
    s = s + c.*(m == u(ii)); 
end
s = (s*5).^2; % Scatter takes square-points size, times 5 for scale
figure; hold on;
for jj = 1:size(m,2)
    scatter(x, m(jj,:), s(jj,:), 'linewidth', 1.25); made
end
hold off;

Comment: You are using `size(m,2)` for the plot loop - that's the number of columns. The plot loop is plotting row-by-row, so you need `size(m,1)`. I've edited my code to include this.

Comment: It works perfectly!
Just one last question, if you don't mind, I want to plot the average of each coloum as a line, 
I tried, define a variable  i=[1:length(m(1,:))];
 yval=[mean(m(:,i))];
 xval=[1:length((1,:))];
and then in the scatter: 
    scatter(x, m(jj,:), s(jj,:), 'linewidth', 1.25,xvals,yvals,'-r');
but it gave me a error message, is it because, I can't plot both things together using scatter?

Comment: @Ryan To plot a mean line, simply put `plot(x, mean(m), '-r', 'linewidth', 1.25); ` **after** the for loop. Also you should get in the habit of using `size(m,1)` rather than `length(m(:,1))`, it's neater and more readable. Consider marking my answer as accepted if it does the job!

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a little jitter? Why not do so uniformly:

```
mat = [0,12,7,10,0,12; 0,7,7,10,0,7; 7,12,-3,0,7,7; 0,10,4,0,7,10];
mat2 = mat' + 0.1 * repmat(1:4, [6 1]) - 0.15;

f1 = figure('Color', ones(1,3));
plot(mat2, '.', 'MarkerSize', 20);
box off;
ax1 = gca;
ax1.XTick = 1:6;
ax1.XLim = [0 7];
```

[image]

I prefer to only add the jitter to the y-axis so the points still line up, but if you want to add it to both the x and y axes, just do this:

```
xvals = repmat(1:6, [4 1])' + 0.1 * repmat(1:4, [6 1]) - 0.25;
plot(xvals, mat2, '.', 'MarkerSize', 20);
```

Comment: This part: repmat(1:4, [6 1]) - 0.15;

I guess it repeats the matrix mat, but I keep getting the error message: 
Matrix dimensions must agree
Error in nr (line 8)
mat2 = mat' + 0.1 * repmat(1:length(mat(:,1)), [6 1]) - 0.15;

I've tried to make it more operable by not define the length, since I don't know the dimensions of the matrix

Comment: @Ryan it looks like you flipped the 4 and the 6 in constructing the `xvals` matrix. That'll make 6 columns of [1 2 3 4] (roughly) which won't work with the plot you're looking for. It's also only looking at the indexes, not any of the values in `mat`. Can't be sure though since both code snippets you have there seem to run fine (independently) for me.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand the code, I've tried to rewrite it so it would work for any dimensions of an N-by-M matrix, but I keep getting the error message matrix dimensions must agree